# How can I speed up painting on a texture in OpenGL? (3.3+/4.1)

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, textures

I am drawing with the mouse on a 3D object.

[image: Teapot with stack overflow written on it]

The way I'm doing it right now is that I pack the UV coordinates via the Fragment shader to the RG pixels as such:

```
in highp vec2 UV;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
    fragColor.r = UV.x;
    fragColor.g = UV.y;
}
```

I render those to an Off-screen FBO, then readPixel under the mouse to get the UV coords on the CPU side.

```
float pixel_array[4];

CALL_GL(glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0));
CALL_GL(glReadPixels(normMouseX*WINDOW_WIDTH,normMouseY*WINDOW_HEIGHT,1,1,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,pixel_array));

float u = pixel_array[0];
float v = pixel_array[1];
```

I then use those UV coordinates to "paint" the texture at the correct location.

```
CALL_GL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mesh.diffuseTexture));
CALL_GL(glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        u*diffuseTextureWidth,
        v*diffuseTextureHeight,
        5,
        5,
        GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        brush_pixels));
```

The problem is that depending on the resolution of the texture, this process is very slow. Is there some way to speed this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I render those to an Off-screen FBO, then readPixel under the mouse to get the UV coords on the CPU side.

Make sure you do readbacks from that texture only when you really need to. Also try to burst the readbacks. Reading a single pixel and that very often is inefficient. Reading the whole texture once ofter it has been updated (after a change of view) is efficient.

To speed up drawing to the texture instead of `glTexSubImage2D`-ing it, just bind it to a FBO as color attachment and draw to it using regular OpenGL drawing operations.

Comment: Huh, I always thought reading from anything on the GPU side was very slow. Your answer is way better than mine though, didn't even think of using OpenGL operations to draw (oh the irony).

Comment: @BWG: It used to be slow, when the connection between GPU and CPU was through the asymmetric bandwidth of AGP. Today we got PCI-E 3 with a symmetric Bandwidth of > 10GiB/s. Using a PBO and well aligned accesses and choosing the native pixel format and layout for the read out buffer the GPU can do an asynchronous DMA transfer. But technically you can do *everything* on a Shader Model 3 GPU, including placing the brush on the target texture. In the Vertex Shader you can read from the geometry buffer texture and distort-place a "brush" grid according to the read back UV coordinates, then draw it.

Comment: Sorry, what is a geometry buffer? Googleing it isn't turning up great results?

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf. When you say PBO you mean adding a pixel buffer object for double-buffering? Also could you please elaborate on "well aligned accesses" (by editing your answer perhaps)?

Comment: @BWG: Geometry buffer is not a OpenGL specific term, but a computer graphics term. In short a geometry buffer is a pixel based buffer where the pixel values do not denote color values, but the geometrical properties of the fragment that got rasterized to said pixel. The texture coordinates are geometrical properties, namely they're the integral of the local (tangent) space  differential of the mesh's surface at that point.

Comment: @Jubei: No. I mean Pixel Buffer Objects. PBOs are kind of proxy objects in OpenGL that allow you to asynchronously transfer pixel data between the GPU and system memory without forcing the GPU into stalling the pipeline through a CPU synchronization event. Essentially you can do a glReadPixels into a PBO with the call to glReadPixels returning immediately. You can than issue further commands to the GPU which can be executed in parallel to the copy operation to the PBO. Later you can then fetch the data from the PBO, and only then the GPU may be required to synchronize.

Comment: @Jubei: The idea of PBOs is to postpone GPU-CPU synchronization, at points in time where such a synch is less disruptive or may be not even cause a disruption at all.

Comment: @datenwolf Rendering to texture didn't make much (if any) difference. I guess the bottleneck is the readPixel operation.

Comment: @Jubei: Yes, glReadPixels is a relatively expensive operation. But keep in mind that you have to transfer the UV geometry buffer image only when the view changed. As long as the view remains constant can reuse the same read back UV data; you don't have to glReadPixels for each any every mouse stroke.

Comment: @datenwolf YES!! That was the big problem. I was rendering at every click/mouse move so that was a big hit on performance. Now that I removed that to update only when the view is changed, it works much much faster!!

Comment: @Jubei: Take note that this is what I was suggesting from the very beginning.

Comment: @datenwolf sorry for revisiting this old answer, but it touches directly on what I'm trying to perform. I guess, I'm having a hard time understanding two concepts. Gonna divide these in two other comments.

Comment: Having the packed Geometry Buffer ( UV coords ), how do I use that information to update the texture? Say that I read the values for all pixels under a square ( representing the brush ), I'm gonna have a list of uv coords representing the pixels that need to be drawn on the texture, but how do I pass that information to GPU painting on the texture? Do I just create a new texture on the GPU each time I want to update, and use that as a color texture input? There's gotta be a better way.

Comment: I didn't fully understand the concept of only reading from the Geometry Buffer in batches, If I only read when the view is about to change. How will the texture be updated as I'm drawing? There won't be a feedback for drawing? I guess I'm confused about this procedure. Would appreciated if you could clarify this, if you'd prefer I can create a fully separated question.